# c++ call class function as callback

Tags: c++

I want to call a class function as callback for my timer but it is fixing out. Next way i try to do is copy a function pointer to another cpp file within the project so someone tell me what is wrong in this.

Header Include File Program:

```
class Progc:

public IStorage
{

public:
Processor(HWND Hwnd);
static void CALLBACK ClickCall(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime);

};
```

Timecatch.cpp file Program

```
void CALLBACK Progc::ClickCall(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId,   DWORD dwTime)
{
    RECT rcOwner; 
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rcOwner);
    SetCursorPos((rcOwner.top), (rcOwner.left));


    this->Action();
    KillTimer(hwnd, 0); 
}
```

The error i get above is

```
error C2671: 'Progc::ClickCall' : static member functions do not have 'this' pointers
error C2227: left of '->Action' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Continue of Timecatch.cpp file Program

```
void Progc::Action()
{
    SetTimer(hWndParent, 0, 6000,(TIMERPROC) &this->ClickCall);   
}
```

Next is another file program file name Program.cpp

```
Progc *ProgBr1;
ProgBr1 = new Processor(hWnd);
```

What i want to do is simple, i want to make `Action()` function call from `ClickCall(....)` Function after the timer call that function, either with other way or by using ProgBr1 pointer like i use ProgBr1 to call Action from Program.cpp.

```
ProgBr1->Action();
```

But i cannot make intialize another variable and get pointer with

```
ProgBr1 = new Processor(hWnd);
```

So is there any way to make another pointer data and copy ProgBr1 value to it and use it in Timecatch.cpp file?

Really confused and new to c++. Will post here if i get any update.

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you fairly clearly what is wrong:

```
static member functions do not have 'this' pointers`
```

That means the call to `this->Action();` is illegal. Callback functions must be `static`, and `static` functions are not passed a hidden `this` pointer by the compiler. In other words, `static` functions are not associated with a particular instance of the class, but rather are general for *all* objects of the class.

There is, unfortunately, no way to pass arbitrary data to a Windows timer callback function. `SetTimer` has no `LPARAM` or equivalent parameter.

In order to make this code work, you must store the pointer with the window associated with the timer. You can do this by using, e.g., [`SetProp()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633568.aspx).

Alternatively, if you have multiple timers associated with a single window, this won't scale well. In this case, you could use a static collection (e.g., `std::map`) to keep track of the data pointers you want to be associated with your timers' IDs.

**Edit:** Assuming that your sample code is really all you are doing and not just a contrived example, it appears that you could make the code work by essentially "inlining" the call to the `Action` member function. I'm not sure what good this will do, but it will compile and run. Perhaps now would be a good place to point out that it is quite unclear to me what the purpose of this code is. Are you just trying to poll continuously and set the cursor position? That is ridiculously pointless. All I have to do is move the mouse and you're screwed. You would have to *constantly* run the timer in a vain attempt to fix the mouse pointer position, which would wreck performance and annoy everyone. Try unplugging the mouse instead.

Comment: How do we SetProp and get it for pointer of function or how do we use std::map for sorting the pointer. can you give a small example?

Comment: Well this is just a part of code with lot of edit to post here. Can you please make example with inlining for the given code above please? if you don't mind.

Comment: I can't really figure out what your code is supposed to do when all you've posted is bits and fragments of it. What is the `Progc` class? What does it do? What is the purpose of the timer? I can show you an example of calling `SetProp()`, but it is really very trivial to do if you have the window handle. The issue is going to be knowing where to put this in your code. And I have no idea, because I don't know what your code does or what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Function marked with static is really static function. It can be called as `Progc::ClickCall(...)` and have no this pointer and have no object reference. It is like usual functions but in the namespace of the class.

It is needed to remove `static` and make it as non static class member. If you need static function, than you need to pass `this` into static function by param or use singleton and fetch class reference from singleton.